# Почему в qt designer картинка отображается, а в окне нет?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

У меня возникла одна очень интересная проблема. Просто смотрите скрины и код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
mainwindow = uic.loadUi("untitled.ui")

if mainwindow.property("fullscreen"):
    mainwindow.showFullScreen()
else:
    mainwindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

untitled.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="windowModality">
   <enum>Qt::ApplicationModal</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1920</width>
    <height>1080</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Maximum">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>PyCSSQt5 user guide</string>
  </property>
  <property name="autoFillBackground">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-image: url(&quot;res/pic/R.jpg&quot;)</string>
  </property>
  <property name="fullscreen" stdset="0">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/pic/R.jpg)</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Просто для начала опубликуйте модуль `untitled.ui` и изображение свое также добавьте.

Comment: @S.Nick А как опубликовать модуль? Извини за тупой вопрос.

Comment: точно так как вы опубликовали `main.py`

Comment: @S.Nick Сейчас...

Comment: Насколько я помню, файлы ресурсов нужно через утилиту компилировать (типа как вы генерировали py из ui), они появятся в виде файлов py. https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qresource-system/ и пример команды `pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources.py`, а в самом файле ui py добавляется импорт `import resources`, тогда магия работает. Еще по этой теме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673900/importing-resource-file-to-pyqt-code

Comment: Бодя, о работе с файлами ресурсов много чего написано. Попробуйте почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2 . Что будет не понятно - спросите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за поддержку @S.Nick, но я разобрался сам. Просто нужно указывать путь к папке, в которой лежит resource-файл вручную,

```
background-image: url("res/pic/R.jpg")
```

а не через двоеточие в начале

```
background-image: url(":/pic/R.jpg")
```

Comment: Вообще-то надо уметь использовать и файлы ресурсов. Очень пригодится.